# Configuration of ssh for mpi running

Tags: ssh, mpi

when i try to run mpi, the question has appeared;

```
The authenticity of host '127.0.1.1 (127.0.1.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:bpYLzdaoHa8vcnSBxjkaUkWv+LTzAA9n6b+kA5EtUvs.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

Then i write "yes", the output is going to write continuously [like in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffo6A.png)

I checked out the ssh status with the command given below

```
sudo systemctl status sshd
```

then the log infos in output are seen like below ;

```
    Feb 06 13:53:21 deskcfd sshd[6748]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
    Feb 06 13:58:36 deskcfd sshd[8509]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
    Feb 06 14:10:51 deskcfd sshd[8922]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
    Feb 06 14:12:24 deskcfd sshd[9156]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 57980 [preauth]
    Feb 06 14:12:51 deskcfd sshd[9176]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 58032 [preauth]
    Feb 06 14:14:27 deskcfd sshd[9190]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
    Feb 06 14:15:15 deskcfd sshd[9200]: error: kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
    Feb 06 14:15:20 deskcfd sshd[9196]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
    Feb 06 14:20:40 deskcfd sshd[9265]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 58656 [preauth]
    Feb 06 14:21:27 deskcfd sshd[9288]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 port 58708 [preauth]
```

It think ssh configuration could solve the mpi problem but i am not sure.

I will be pleased if you help me.

Comment: Unless you are using a supported resource manager, MPI requires password less SSH access between nodes. The first time a new host is connected to, SSH will require you to accept the remote host key fingerprint (e.g. type "yes" and you're done). Note you are connecting to `127.0.1.1` which is an odd address in the loopback network, and this is generally **not** what you want to do. use private networks instead e.g. (subnets of) `10/8`, `172.16/12` or `192.168/16`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet unless the system has a static network address, the IP for the system's hostname in `/etc/hosts` is `127.0.1.1`. It's an old convention, afaik coming from Debian.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Now it begs the question : “why is SSH involved here?”

Comment: @HristoIliev my system has a static network address.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you for your reply. How can i use private networks?

Comment: First you should post your `mpirun` command line, and `machinefile` if any

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Sorry but i am beginner in linux. I did not understand what you mean by machinefile

Comment: no problem, just post your `mpirun` command line.